# JMeter and Java web service stop after hours

Tags: web-services, jmeter

I am trying to test a stress test a web service using JMeter but the requests keep stopping after around 4 hours.

I submit 10 requests per second from JMeter. The web service is still functioning properly after JMeter completes. 
I am using only 1 soap request and I do not specify to rad the soap response.

Why JMeter gives up after a certain amount of time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several suggestions to check:

1. Use the latest version of JMeter.
2. Use latest/different JDK version/vendor.
3. Try running JMeter in command line mode (in case you have run it in GUI before).
4. Check networking/firewall setup between your client and your server.